# browsing with server ip address not loading static content?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have searched the web i  could not find an answer to my problem.

I have windows server 2012 R2.

I deployed a .net website in the server.

browsing the website using the server ip adress does not load the static content (css,images, js) ?

However if I go to IIS and browse the website static contents get loaded.

In the IIS manager, I have binding to the some domain ex.ae.com. but this domain DNS pointing to another server currently. I wanna test my new server first, when things goes fine, i Will point that domain to the new server. But in order for me to do so. I have to first test the current server.

Any reason why browsing with IP address does not load static content ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a *programming* question here? It sounds more like a server configuration issue which is probably better asked on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I understand but also web developers will face this issue alot, so I thought it was a good idea to share this problem here. Otherwise I can delete it ,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open to users access to read your path?

User: IIS_USRS

Rights: Read